# SQL Server Ltrim or substring to get the email address only

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have this scenario:

```
John Doe johndoe@email.com
John johndoe@email.com
```

I want away that would only parse out this as following:

```
John Doe
John
```

In other words, removing the email address only.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
                (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(‘ ‘, REVERSE(column1)) > 0 THEN Left(column1, CHARINDEX(‘ ‘, REVERSE(column1)) – 1)
                ELSE column1
                END) AS column1
FROM Book1
```

Comment: I edited the post with what I have tried. Thank you Michael.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146268/sql-server-rtrim-ltrim-and-charindex/19146361#19146361

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track... just add the len function and drop the "minus 1"

```
SELECT  (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(column1)) > 0 THEN Left(column1, len (column1) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(column1)))
                ELSE column1
                END) AS column1
FROM Book1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = 'John Doe johndoe@email.com'


 SELECT LEFT(@Str, LEN(@Str) - LEN(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Str), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@Str)) - 1))))
```